# Does Ubuntu One support SOCKS 5 (SSH Tunneling)?

Tags: ubuntu-one, ssh

I cannot make the Ubuntu One to run under SSH Tunneling (Dynamic Port Forwarding).  Does it support SSH Tunneling?

If yes, how to set it up, thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,